# Getting variables from content of file

Tags: php, file, variables, preg-match-all

I have php language files and i'm including to my project.

For example: content of **en.php**

```
<?php
$lng["home"]="Home Page";
$lng["my_account"]="My Account";
$lng["administrator"]="Administrator";
$lng["logout"]="Logout";
```

I want to change the file content in administration page.

Since the file is included, $lng variable already defined.
So when I include the file again it overwrites the existing $lng variable.

I did this by changing the key of the old variable.
Like this:

```
$old_lng = $lng; 
include ("file"); 
$last_included_lng = $lng; 
$lng = $last_included_lng;
```

is that best way?

Comment: What if you just _include_ the file?

Comment: There is $lng variable already.

Answer (score 0):

Include the file.

`include 'en.php';`

Then all of your `$lng` items will be overwritten, it essentially runs the content of `en.php` as if it were written in the same file.

Comment: A comment should have worked perfectly! BTW: the correct usage ist _include 'file.php'_

Comment: I have already $lng variable; 
$lng=array('xxx');

include(file);
and $lng will change.

Why -1 ? :)

Comment: Maybe I can do;
$old_lng = $lng;
include ("file");
$new_lng = $lng;
$lng = $old_lng;

but  is that best way?

Comment: Do you need to catch the variables in the file no matter what they're called?

Answer (score 0):

A way to be independent from the variable name is to return the array directly.

That will look like:

```
<?php
return [
    'home'       => 'Home Page',
    'my_account' => 'My Account',
    // and so on
];
```

You can assogn this by using `$foo = include('en.php');`.